# Subclassing a class that has a "factory" method

Tags: ruby

I have a class that has a "factory" method which returns new instances given a file_name.  Depending on the type of file given it needs to construct the object differently.  It also happens to be a swig generated class wrapping a c++ class, I am not sure that matters, but I am including that detail just in case it does.  So I have this class defined somewhere, which has among other things this `new_from_file` method

```
class Wv::WvWaveList 
  def self.new_from_file file_name
     ... 
      Wv::WaveList.new
  end
  ....
end
```

I wanted to add a method `copy_wave`, so my first thought was to subclass and add it there so something like this.

```
class MyWaveList < Wv::WvWaveList
  def copy_wave
    ...        
  end
end
```

The problem is that new_from_file still returns a Wv::WaveList not a MyWaveList so I can't call `copy_wave` on instances returned by `new_from_file`

One simple solution is to just open the class up here and add the method

```
class Wv::WvWave
  def copy_wave
     ...
  end
end
```

Another solution would be to have MyWaveList have an instance of a Wv::WaveList and delegate all the appropriate calls to that instance.

So I am just wondering what the inheritance solution might be?  I just don't see it right now.

Comment: instead of calling `Wv::WaveList.new` in `self.new_from_file`, couldn't you call `self.new`, so that `self` refers to the class being acted upon? I tested this out, and the new instance was a `MyWaveList` instead of a `Wv::WaveList`

Comment: That's what I was missing.  In one of the methods deeper down (called by new_from_file) I had a call to Wv::WaveList.new,  I monkey patched that method to call self.new,  and then subclassing works as expected.  I understand what's going on, but feel free to submit an answer explaining explaining what's going on, and I will accept it.  In the end I will fix this issue directly in the class (since I own it) and also probably just add copy_waves to the class anyway (since it would be useful)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this should work

```
class Wv::WvWaveList 
  def self.new_from_file file_name
    ... 
    self.new
  end
  ....
end
```

Because `self.new_from_file` was always calling `Wv::WaveList.new`, it was always instantiating objects with that class, even from subclasses. But by using `self`, you'll be able to call `new_from_file` on any subclass, and the objects will be of the correct class:

```
>> a = MyWaveList.new_from_file "some_file"
=> #<MyWaveList:0x007fd473004318 @file_name="some_file">
>> a.class
=> MyWaveList
```